How do I send to multiple email addresses without all emails being seen in the "To" section of each email?
I can send emails to multiple people with SendGrid in .Net, that's not the issue. It's when an email recipient gets his email he can see all other email addresses from all the other recipients.
QUESTION - How do I send all my emails out to the recipients from a list (array), but not show all other recipients?
I tried changing msg.AddTos() to msg.AddBccs() but that didn't seem to even send out the emails at all, or at least I didn't get them.
Ex. Here is what the recipient see's when he opens his email. He can see his email "Test Roy" and all other email recipients.

Here is my function that send the email.


private async Task < Response > ExecuteTemplate(string[] toEmailAddresses, string subject, dynamic templateData) {
  var client = new SendGridClient(sendGridOptions.SendGridKey);
  var msg = new SendGridMessage();
  msg.SetFrom(new EmailAddress("automated@mysite.com", "MySite"));
  msg.SetTemplateId(_config["SendGrid:TemplateId"]);
  templateData.subject = subject;
  msg.SetTemplateData(templateData);

  if (toEmailAddresses.Length > 1) {
    var emailAddresses = toEmailAddresses.Select(array => new EmailAddress(array)).ToList();
    // msg.AddBccs(emailAddresses);
    msg.AddTos(emailAddresses);
  } else {
    msg.AddTo(toEmailAddresses[0]);
  }

  msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);
  msg.SetOpenTracking(false);
  msg.SetGoogleAnalytics(false);
  msg.SetSubscriptionTracking(false);

  var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

  return response;
}




BCC is the right answer. Just remember that will also make it look more like spam. An alternative is to send to each addressee separately (so send many emails), but that could also trigger anti-spam measures (including at your provider).

I'm reading through the SendGrid docs and I think personalizations is what I need? https://www.twilio.com/en-us/blog/bulk-email-with-csharp-and-dotnet#Bulk-email-using-Personalizations

@Oldboy - I think I tried adding all my receipients as Bcc's but then I didn't get any emails at all! Unless I did something else that messed up the delivery...

Apologies, I wanted to edit my message, but deleted it by mistake. Using Bcc is the standard method of doing this, and has been since email was first created. If it does not work for you then maybe you need to investigate your client email library (SendGrid), and your mail server.

You need to make sure there is at least one "To" (and the rest as Bccs), otherwise nothing gets sent

C# SendGrid supports mailing which shows all recipients in the email via
CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients (L269 - L275)
public static SendGridMessage CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(
    EmailAddress from,
    List<EmailAddress> tos,
    string subject,
    string plainTextContent,
    string htmlContent,
    bool showAllRecipients = false)

By default, the showAllRecipients parameter is set to false. If you compare the code between the function above when providing showAllRecipients = true and L97 - L102:
L292
msg.AddTos(tos);

L119
msg.AddTo(tos[i], i);

This is the difference of not showing all the (To) recipients in the email.
Thus, as you are using the CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients or CreateSingleTemplateEmailToMultipleRecipients method, this will create the email message without showing all recipients.
private async Task<Response> ExecuteTemplate(string[] toEmailAddresses, string subject, dynamic templateData) 
{
    templateData.subject = subject;

    var client = new SendGridClient(sendGridOptions.SendGridKey);
    var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleTemplateEmailToMultipleRecipients(
        new EmailAddress("automated@mysite.com", "MySite"),
        toEmailAddresses.Select(array => new EmailAddress(array)).ToList(),
        _config["SendGrid:TemplateId"].ToString(),
        templateData
    );

  msg.SetClickTracking(false, false);
  msg.SetOpenTracking(false);
  msg.SetGoogleAnalytics(false);
  msg.SetSubscriptionTracking(false);

  var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);

  return response;
}

Otherwise, you can try maintaining your existing code, but making changes here:
if (toEmailAddresses.Length > 1) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < toEmailAddresses.Count(); i++)
    {
        msg.AddTos(new EmailAddress(toEmailAddresses[i]), i);
    }
}


What if I'm using a template? CreateSingleTemplateEmailToMultipleRecipients()

Additionally, showAllRecipients doesn't seem to be in the newest version. The one you linked to is 4 years old!

The last commit is 4 years ago, doesn't mean that it is an old/archive code, as I am using the main branch. Based on the latest release 9.29.3, they still use showAllRecipients. The concept CreateSingleTemplateEmailToMultipleRecipients and CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients are the same which will not show all recipients.

I'm experiencing another issue when using personalizations, I posted a link here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/78486474/1186050

Using "bcc" is the way to hide emails to other recipients, but you need to set at least one "to" recipient.
A good solution is to set the "to" the same as the sender, or a service email used specifically for this purpose.
This is to avoid send a separate email to each recipient, that's even a solution but not optimal.

Relax - there were two minutes between your answers, and Davide Messori could have been writing their answer in those two minutes, and did not see yours before posting.

I am sorry man, i saw your answer in the instant i posted, we were writing at the same time i guess. And the answers are of course similar, it’s just we both have the same solution.
