Not receiving all distribution group emails to same Outlook account email address using SendGrid to send
Scenario - I'm using the SendGrid API to send emails from my Azure server. I've have purchased an email address from GoDaddy.com

test@contoso.com

Under this email account (in GoDaddy's dashboard) I created multiple distribution groups for this email for testing purposes. Ex. mark@contoso.com, luke@contoso.com, tom@contoso.com So when I send out some test emails to a group of people (ex. tom, mark) they all get received by test@contoso.com and I can filter them into different folders in my Outlook account inbox. This works fine if I send a single email (mark@contoso.com) or if I send multiple emails but use SendGrid's function
msg.AddTos(emailAddresses);

the problem with AddTos() is every recipient can see all other recipient's email addresses. So I want to fix that...
Problem - I modified the code below to use personalizations, but when I send out multiple emails to my different distributions groups (ex. mark@contoso.com, luke@contoso.com) I only receive one email out of the many that were sent. I don't receive more than 1!
I looked at my SendGrid dashboard and all the emails show a delivered status, which means they received an ok() from Outlooks server.
If I try and send just 1 email at a time I have no problem, but if I send multiple emails I receive just one. Additionally, I receive a IsSuccessStatusCode of true back from the sendEmailAsync() call. So I'm not getting any errors on my(application) side.
Recap, if I send a group of emails using NO personalizations I receive them all but I don't receive them all if I use personalizations! But I need to use personalizations because I don't want each email recipient to see everyone else I'm sending emails too.
// without works!
sendGridMessage.AddTo(new EmailAddress(toEmailAddresses[i]));
// with doesn't work in receiving all emails in my inbox
sendGridMessage.AddTo(new EmailAddress(toEmailAddresses[i]), i);

Question - Is there an issue with personalizations with Outlook How would I know?
Here is my code.


dynamic templateData = new JObject();
templateData.name = "Test";
templateData.text = "Testing";

// works! email received
var emails = new string[] {"test1@gmail.com"};

// doesn't work! only some emails received
var emails = new string[] {"test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com", "test3@gmail.com"};

// send email
await _emailService.ExecuteTemplate(emails, "Test Subject" templateData);


// function
public async Task<Response> ExecuteTemplate(string[] toEmailAddresses, string subject, dynamic templateData) {
  var client = new SendGridClient(sendGridOptions.SendGridKey);

  var sendGridMessage = new SendGridMessage() {
    From = new EmailAddress(_config["SendGrid:Server"], "Yogabandy"),
      TemplateId = _config["SendGrid:TemplateId"]
  };
  templateData.subject = subject;

  for (int i = 0; i < toEmailAddresses.Length; i++) {
    sendGridMessage.AddTo(new EmailAddress(toEmailAddresses[i]), i);
    sendGridMessage.SetTemplateData(templateData, i);
  }

  var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(sendGridMessage);

  if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    _logger.LogInformation("Email queued");
  } else {
    _logger.LogError("Email not queued. Satus Code: " + response.StatusCode);
  }

  return response;
}




Have you tried awaiting the ExecuteTemplate call? It is an async process. Try await _emailService.ExecuteTemplate(...).

Why does the BCC not work in your case ?

Can you create a Personalizations object in your sendGridMessage and populate it with Tos? Personalizations = new List { new Personalization
{
Tos = new List();
for(int i = 0; i < toEmailAddresses.Length; i++)
{
Tos.Add(new EmailAddress(toEmailAddresses[i], i));
}
}
}   https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/blob/main/src/SendGrid/Helpers/Mail/SendGridMessage.cs#L166. The code creates a new Personalization object for each email that you append

@SoftwareDveloper I don't believe my issue is with how I've coded the SendGrid calls, but with something on the Outlook handling side. I've tried a multitude of different ways to send the emails (multiple to's, adding bcc's, etc) and they all show delivered on the SendGrid dashboard. There's an issue with receiving them all, which I can only correlate with the Outlook handling of multiple distribution groups being received all at once to a single email domain!??
